# fastify validation with nestJs?

Tags: nestjs, fastify

is there any ways of using fastify validation in nestJs app?
fastify validation

```js
fastify.post('/user', {
  schema: {
    body: {
      type: 'object',
      required: ['name', 'email'],
      properties: {
        name: { type: 'string' },
        email: { type: 'string', format: 'email' }
      }
    }
  }
}, async (request, reply) => {
  return { hello: request.body.name }
})
```

but how to use it in nestJs?

Comment: Isn't easier to migrate your schemas to Zod or Class-validator?

Comment: fastify faster then class-validator, and that's the reason nestia was created, but I just wonder if I could use fastify instead, cause nestia dies not supports babel)